# React not re-rendering on change

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, state

So I've been beating my head against a wall for a couple days now scouring through Google and questions on here. I've done quite a bit of changes to the code I've written and re-written. The problem I'm getting is that the POST request to the DB works fine. If I refresh the page, the new entry is there. Somewhere in my code, I know I'm not properly updating the state. From what I've gathered, an issue like mine happens when you're not passing a new array into state in order for a re-render to trigger.

At this point I'm lost, and any insight on to what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
export default function Form () {

const [chatData, setChatData] = useState([{
    chat: Number,
    isConverted: Boolean,
}])

console.log(chatData)

const changeHandler = name => (e) => {
    setChatData({...chatData, [name]: e.target.value})
}

const createChat = (e) =>  {
    e.preventDefault()

    const data = { ...chatData }

    const postData = () => {
        try {
            axios.post("/api/create", data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
        }
    }
    postData()
}

return (
    <div>
        <Box sx={{maxWidth: 200}} display="flex" alignItems="center" justifyContent="center" margin="auto">
            <form onSubmit={createChat}> 
                    <FormControl fullWidth sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }}>
                        <InputLabel id="chat_number_label">Chat Number</InputLabel>
                        <Select
                        labelId="chat_number_label"
                        id="chat_input_select"
                        defaultValue=""
                        value={chatData.chat}
                        onChange={changeHandler("chat")}
                        name="chat">
                            <MenuItem value={1}>1</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={2}>2</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={3}>3</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={4}>4</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={5}>5</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={6}>6</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={7}>7</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={8}>8</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={9}>9</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={10}>10</MenuItem>
                        </Select>
                        </FormControl>
                        <FormControl fullWidth sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }}>
                        <InputLabel id="is_converted_label">Converted to Ticket</InputLabel>
                        <Select
                        labelId="is_converted_label"
                        id="is_converted_select"
                        defaultValue=""
                        value={chatData.isConverted}
                        onChange={changeHandler("isConverted")}
                        name="isConverted">
                            <MenuItem value={true}>True</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem value={false}>False</MenuItem>
                        </Select>
                    </FormControl>
                <Button color="primary" variant="contained" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</Button>
            </form>
        </Box>
    </div>
)
}
```

EDIT: Per request, this is where all my chats are displayed on the page

```
export default function AllChats () {

const [chatList, setChatList] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAllChats = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get("/api")
            setChatList(res.data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
        }
    }
    fetchAllChats()
}, [])

const headers = [
    {
        label: "Chat Number", key: "chat"
    },
    {
        label: "Date", key: "createdAt"
    },
    {
        label: "Converted into Ticket", key:"isConverted"
    }
]

const csvLink = {
    filename: "chat_data.csv",
    headers: headers,
    data: chatList
}

return (
    <Container  maxWidth="md">
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }}>
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>Chats Number</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Date</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Converted into ticket</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                { chatList.map((val, _key) => {
                    return (
                    <TableRow key={val.chat}
                                sx={{ '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': { border: 0 } }}
                        >
                            <TableCell omponent="th" scope="row">{val.chat}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">{val.createdAt}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right"> {String(val.isConverted)} </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                )})}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
        <CSVLink {...csvLink}>Export to CSV</CSVLink>
    </Container>
)
}
```

Here's my App.js

```
    function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <AllChats />
    <Form />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: your initial chatdata is an array but the onChange setchatdata is an object. Is there a reason for this change?

Comment: @raman no, there is no reason. I was just testing something. If I change the setChatData to an array would this work?

Comment: Your state is being updated when the input values change. I don't see where in the code you are displaying the chats. It would be helpful if you posted more code as I don't think the problem is here (besides removing the array wrapping `chat` and `isConverted` in your state)

Comment: @gloo Added more code for context. When removing the Array mapping, the Select inputs end up breaking. If I change the value, it doesn't keep the change and won't allow me to submit.

Comment: EDIT: I removed the array wrapping around my initial state. I made a mistake when testing something, so it works in terms of how it did to begin with. After removing the array mapping, it still doesn't render on change though.

Answer (score 0):

You are initiating chatData State with an OBJECT, but with-in an array like this:

```
const [chatData, setChatData] = useState([{
    chat: Number,
    isConverted: Boolean,
}])
```

So when you are retrieving the `chatData`, it is returning the array, not the object.

You need to remove the array while initiating it, and directly initiate it with an OBJECT like this:

```
const [chatData, setChatData] = useState({
    chat: Number,
    isConverted: Boolean,
})
```

It will solve the problem.

And if don't, then you can contact me through my profile.

Comment: So, I'm not able to DM you at all, but when making that change it breaks my input completely. When I change a value on the select inputs, the change doesn't stay.

Comment: This is my Instagram Id: https://www.instagram.com/shaikh_khizr/
Contact me through here

Answer (score 0):

`setChatList` is only called on first render in `fetchAllChats`. Your `chatList` is never being updated after the `post` request in `createChat`. You are updating your database but your frontend has no knowledge that your chats were updated. You need to update your `chatList` with `setChatList` upon a successful `post`. For instance:

```
axios.post("/api/create", data).then(response => {
    setChatList([...chatList, response.data]);
})
```

For the above to work, your backend should return the `chat` in the response in the same format as in the `get` request in `fetchAllChats()`. Or the response could contain the entire updated chat list. If you don't have control over the backend, you could run `fetchAllChats()` after a successful  POST, but this might not be ideal as it is additional load in terms of network and database operations.

In either case, you would need access to functions from `<AllChats />` like  `setChatList` in your `<Form />` component, so you should [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to a common ancestor (`<App />` in this case)

Comment: So do I need put both the GET and POST in the same functional component, or could I run an if statement to get this done?

Comment: If you have control over the API on the server-side, you could use the response from the `POST` which is less overhead than making a `GET` request immediately after your `POST`